# Convert matrices in list to same dimensions in R

Tags: r, matrix, size

1) I have a list of matrices.

2) I need each matrix in the list to have the same number of rows (specifically 508).

3) each matrix in the list is of different size.

4) Fill all remaining rows (up to column number) with NAs.

setup:

```
mat1 <- data.frame(matrix(nrow =20, ncol =60, data=rnorm(20*60,0,1)))
mat2 <- data.frame(matrix(nrow =20, ncol =63, data=rnorm(20*63,0,1)))
mat3 <- data.frame(matrix(nrow =23, ncol =66, data=rnorm(23*66,0,1)))

list1 <- c(mat1,mat2,mat3)
```

So i need mat1 to be converted into a 508x60 matrix (rows 21-508 being filled with NAs), mat2 to be 508x63 matrix(rows 21-508 being filled with NAs) etc.

my actual data consists of a list of 100 matrices, so i would prefer not to do this one by one.

Comment: So just to clarify since your requirements 2) and 3) seem to contradict each other somewhat: The matrices should have the same number of rows but different number of columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can create matrices with `NA` and `rbind` to the original one

```
n <- 508
lapply(list1, function(x) rbind(x, matrix(ncol = ncol(x), nrow = n - nrow(x))))
```

Also this is assuming all the matrices have less than `n` rows. If there could be a case where rows in matrix is more than `n` then we should use `nrow = pmax(n - nrow(x), 0)`.

---

If the list is a list of dataframe (and not matrix) here are few options :

Using the same approach as we used for matrix but wrap `data.frame` and then `rbind`

```
lapply(list1, function(x) rbind(x, 
             data.frame(matrix(ncol = ncol(x), nrow = n - nrow(x)))))
```

With dataframe, we can also directly subset the number of rows required. It would directly give `NA`'s for rows which do not exist.

```
lapply(list1, function(x) x[seq_len(n), ])
```

However, it gives weird rownames for `NA` values. If we want to remove the rownames, we can do

```
lapply(list1, function(x) {x <- x[seq_len(n), ];rownames(x) <- NULL;x})
```

**data**

```
set.seed(123)
mat1 <- matrix(nrow =20, ncol =60, data=rnorm(20*60,0,1))
mat2 <- matrix(nrow =20, ncol =63, data=rnorm(20*63,0,1))
mat3 <- matrix(nrow =23, ncol =66, data=rnorm(23*66,0,1))
list1 <-list(mat1,mat2,mat3)
```

Comment: can i make an adjustment:

Your code doesn't seem to work when I change the setup to:


mat1 <- data.frame(matrix(nrow =20, ncol =60, data=rnorm(20*60,0,1)))
mat2 <- data.frame(matrix(nrow =20, ncol =63, data=rnorm(20*63,0,1)))
mat3 <- data.frame(matrix(nrow =23, ncol =66, data=rnorm(23*66,0,1)))

Comment: You could also do `lapply(list1, function(d) as.data.frame(lapply(d, \`length<-\`, n)))`.

Answer (score 1):

An option is to use `mapply` on the number of columns and rows.

```
ncol <- c(60, 63, 66)
nrow <- c(20, 20, 23)
nmax <- 508
lst <- mapply(
    function(nc, nr) {
        mat <- matrix(nrow = nmax, ncol = nc, NA)
        mat[1:nr, 1:nc] <- rnorm(ncol * nrow, 0, 1)
        mat
    },
    ncol,
    nrow)
```

Explanation: The idea is to generate matrices of dimension `508 x nc` consisting only of `NA`; then fill the `nr x nc` submatrix with values from `rnorm(...)`. The output is the desired `list` of matrices.